# How to add data or change schema to production database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am new to working with databases and I want to make sure I understand the best way to add or remove data from a database without making a mess of any related data.

Here is a scenario I am working with:

I have a **Tags** table, with an Identity ID column. The Tags can be selected via the web application to categorize stories that are submitted by a user. When the database was first seeded; like tags were seeded in order together. As you can see all the Campuses (cities) were 1-4, the Colleges (subjects) are 5-7, and Populations are 8-11.

If this database is live in production and the client wants to add a new Campus (City) tag, what is the best way to do this?

All the other city tags are sort of organized at the top, it seems like the only option is to insert any *new* tags at to bottom of the table, where they will end up taking whatever the next ID available is. I suppose this is fine because the Display category column will allow us to know which categories these new tags actually belong to.

Is this typical? Is there better ways to set up the database or handle this situation such that everything remains more organized?

Thank you

```
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| ID |   DisplayName    | DisplayDetail | DisplayCategory | DisplayOrder | Active | ParentID |
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Albany           | NULL          |               1 |            0 |      1 | NULL     |
|  2 | Buffalo          | NULL          |               1 |            1 |      1 | NULL     |
|  3 | New York City    | NULL          |               1 |            2 |      1 | NULL     |
|  4 | Syracuse         | NULL          |               1 |            3 |      1 | NULL     |
|  5 | Business         | NULL          |               2 |            0 |      1 | NULL     |
|  6 | Dentistry        | NULL          |               2 |            1 |      1 | NULL     |
|  7 | Law              | NULL          |               2 |            2 |      1 | NULL     |
|  8 | Student-Athletes | NULL          |               3 |            0 |      1 | NULL     |
|  9 | Alumni           | NULL          |               3 |            1 |      1 | NULL     |
| 10 | Faculty          | NULL          |               3 |            2 |      1 | NULL     |
| 11 | Staff            | NULL          |               3 |            3 |      1 | NULL     |
+----+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: It's typical.  The problem you are going to have though is maintaining the DisplayOrder column as you get more and more records.

Comment: @DanBracuk good point... I actually run into ordering issues like that especially when creating & altering seed data. I have yet to figure out a good way to handle that. Is there a solution to better manage that?

Comment: The best way I've found is to have a view for every category with triggers to handle DML. This solves several problems. A dropdown list that shows only cities can have the Cities view as its only data object. Ditto with the Majors dropdown and so forth. They won't have to even know about display categories or active flags (an inactive entry will not even appear in the view). Maintenance can also be done through the views. The Delete trigger can just flip the Active flag if that is the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

The terms "top" and "bottom" which you use aren't really applicable. "Albany" isn't at the "Top" of the table - it's merely at the top of the specific view you see when you query the table without specifying a meaningful sort order. It defaults to a sort order based on the Id or an internal ROWID parameter, which isn't the *logical* way to show this data.

Data in the table isn't inherently ordered. If you want to view your tags organized by their category, simply order your query by `DisplayCategory` (and probably by `DisplayOrder` afterwards), and you'll see your data properly organized. You can even create a persistent View that sorts it that way for your convenience.